# Why is output Black and white in a RGB format after passing a color image through my denoising model?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I want construct a model to denoise image. But after training it is always putting out a gray scale like image in RGB format. I tried many loss function from as complex as **mssim,psnr** to simple like **mae**, but still got the same result.

I trying to implement something like this - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08921v3.pdf
like a symmetric skip autoencoder

i.e[image: The gray scale image]

Here is my model

```
inputs = Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))



layer1 = Conv2D(3, strides = (2,2),kernel_size=4,padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(512, 512, 3))(inputs)
layer2 = Conv2D(3, strides =(2,2),kernel_size=4,padding='same', activation='relu')(layer1)
layer3 = Conv2D(3, strides =(2,2),kernel_size=4,padding='same', activation='relu')(layer2)
layer4 = Conv2D(3, strides = (2,2),kernel_size=4,padding='same', activation='relu')(layer3)
layer5 = Conv2DTranspose(3,strides=(2, 2),kernel_size = 4,padding='same',activation='relu') (layer4)
merge1 = maximum([layer3,layer5])/2
layer6 = Conv2DTranspose(3,strides=(2, 2),kernel_size = 4,padding='same',activation='relu') (layer5)
merge2 = maximum([layer2,layer6])/2
layer7 = Conv2DTranspose(3,strides=(2, 2),kernel_size = 4,padding='same',activation='relu') (merge2)
merge3 = Add()([layer1,layer7])/2
layer8 = Conv2DTranspose(3,strides=(2, 2),kernel_size = 4,padding='same',activation='relu') (merge3)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer8)
```

please help me what to solve this problem or any other suggestion about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your filters are too less. You filters should increase as the depth increases. Keep them in powers of 2 such as 32, 64, 128 and so on.

Your kernel size is 4x4. Why? The usual kernels used are 3x3 or 5x5. Even kernels are bad at learning than odd kernels. Try using 3x3 and then, 5x5 if 3x3 doesn't work.

Comment: Well I tried with more filter and the results were the same. Also I tried with 5*5 as well and again it was gray scale.